Sonos custom content service/integration - Cover art not showing on Now Playing
I'm developing a custom Content Integration for playing audiobooks. Everything is working well, except cover art (or albumArt) isn't showing in the "Now Playing" window. The list view shows the cover art correctly when choosing an audiobook but when playing the book, the cover art isn't shown.
Am I missing something obvious needed to make album art work for the Now Playing screen? I looked into using "Image Replacement Rules" in the Content Integration configuration (following https://docs.sonos.com/docs/add-album-art), but it didn't seem to do anything (I see no replaced requests hitting the image server) and it seemed like this would be more of an optimization than a necessity to get album artwork working, but perhaps I'm doing something wrong...
I am supplying an albumArtURI for both the audiobook mediaCollection and the individual tracks (mediaCollections) of the form:

http://192.168.1.100/cover/${libraryItem.id}_200.png

I tried the substitution rule:

Pattern: .+(?<size>_200\.png)
Name: 1000
Replacement Text: _1000.png

I've looked into other older codebases where they seem to register the service with a <PresentationMap type="ArtWorkSizeMap">, but I'm assuming this approach has been replaced with the 'Image Replacement Rules'.
I tried supplying an SVG file and that showed up on the mobile app, but not on the Mac Sonos app (presumably), so I suspect it does relate to the image substitution, since I assume SVG removes the need.
Can anyone help here? Thanks!
